irq/9-acpi process using 27% cpu
I see this process constantly using 20+% cpu
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
129 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  27.2   0.0      9,04 [irq/9-acpi]

What is this process? And can I config something not to use as much so often?
I'm using Manjaro with Gnome
Linux radu-gram 6.9.0-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 13 07:01:28 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Found a solution, by a Reddit user, but the subreddit was removed so posting it here

After searching on the internet for long it turned out it's because
the BIOS needs an update (info I found was scarce so I didn't verify
it and I don't like taking risks with the motherboard).
These kinds of interrupts make the CPU go crazy.
You have 2 ways of shutting them off:
Permanent Install a cron implementation:

Install cronie

sudo pacman -Sy --needed cronie
sudo systemctl enable cronie


create a crontab to mask and disable the crazy interrupts

@reboot echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci 
@reboot echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6E 
@reboot echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci 
@reboot echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6E


load the crontab you saved to root user
sudo crontab -u root < FILENAME

start the service
sudo systemctl start cronie


Typically it should shut them off every
time you power on your PC but it worked for me when I started the
service even before rebooting.
Keep the crontab file you created somewhere safe (in your dotfiles or something) because you'll need it every time you install Linux on the same machine.
Temporary
Use highest privilege shell
su
run the commands
echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci
echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6E
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/sci
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6E

This will work now but won't work next time you reboot.

